# Different instances of NSDate pointing to the same allocated memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsdate

I'm creating tests where I have to make sure 2 different NSDate instances are really two different instances of allocated memory. So I have this example code:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:date1];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(date1, date2);
XCTAssertNotEqual(date1, date2);
```

The first assert should compare object values using "isEqual", and it's working great!

The second assert should compare pointers using "==". The bizarre thing is that it sometimes fails randomly, telling me that both pointers have the same value (ie, they are pointing to the same allocated memory).

As I'm allocating twice, it is supposed to be different memory areas... So why do I have this test failing randomly sometimes? Maybe XCode is reusing memory areas somehow?

Comment: You're unit testing something you shouldn't be testing, because you have no control over it.

Comment: Obviously your unit test works perfectly fine by telling you that your assumptions about pointers were incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably force the creation of separate objects. Some classes may use tagged pointers. The set of classes doing that can change over time with releases of the OS. A tagged pointer really just encodes the value of the object into a pointer-sized value. It doesn't allocate any memory. By definition, any two objects represented as tagged pointers whose values are equal will have equal "addresses".

Also, an init method is just a method. It can return any object it wants. There's no rule that it has to return the receiver. It can release the `alloc`ed object it is sent to (`self`) and return a different object. If it can determine that an existing object (such as the parameter you're passing to `-initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:`) meets its needs, it may return that object (with an extra retain). This sort of thing is common in immutable value classes, like `NSDate` or `NSString`.

You're going to have to reconsider your supposed need to "make sure 2 different NSDate instances are really two different instances of allocated memory".

Comment: Tagged pointer details by Mike Ash: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html, which are, AFAIK, currently used for NSDate.

Comment: Yes NSDate does sometimes use NSTaggedDate